# Mongodb error. Server doesn't run

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am learning complete web development course from Udemy. Working in Cloud9. When I start my Mongodb server, I get this:

[image]

Comment: in terminal, what's the result of `df -h`

Comment: @Alex`Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none                      2.2G  658M  1.4G  33% /
tmpfs                      26G     0   26G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      26G     0   26G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata  1.2T  582G  600G  50% /mnt
shm                        64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error log, you will see it is telling you that you need to allocate more space for journals (line 14 on the picure).

Comment: Tell me please, how can I do that?

Comment: I would go with the smallfiles option first, just start your mongod with the option --smallfiles.

Answer (score 0):

`>> /data/db/journal` - this should create the journal file manually.

If you still get this error check how much free disk u have in ur server.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mongod` using the following options:

`mongod --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles`

This will reduce the initial size of the journal files. More information on the `smallfiles` option (and generally the configuration file options) is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.smallFiles).